# Generate auth token for accessing CR in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-acr

I'm authenticating against Azure using a service principal, and I'd like to convert a shell script to Java. My shell script code essentially does this:

```
export AAD_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --query accessToken -o tsv)

export ACR_REFRESH_TOKEN=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d "grant_type=access_token&service=$REGISTRY&access_token=$AAD_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    https://$REGISTRY/oauth2/exchange \
    | jq '.refresh_token' \
    | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
echo "ACR Refresh Token obtained."
# Create the repo level scope
SCOPE="repository:$REPOSITORY:pull"

# to pull multiple repositories passing in multiple scope arguments.
#&scope="repository:repo:pull,push"

export ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d "grant_type=refresh_token&service=$REGISTRY&scope=$SCOPE&refresh_token=$ACR_REFRESH_TOKEN" \
    https://$REGISTRY/oauth2/token \
    | jq '.access_token' \
    | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
echo "ACR Access Token obtained."
```

I'm trying to find the Java equivalents for

`az account get-access-token --query accessToken -o tsv`

and

`curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=access_token&service=$REGISTRY&access_token=$AAD_ACCESS_TOKEN"     https://$REGISTRY/oauth2/exchange | jq '.refresh_token' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'`

and

`curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=refresh_token&service=$REGISTRY&scope=$SCOPE&refresh_token=$ACR_REFRESH_TOKEN" https://$REGISTRY/oauth2/token | jq '.access_token' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'`

but haven't really found any documentation on how to do this using Java. I found this: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/wiki/Acquire-tokens for acquiring AAD tokens but nothing on that page tells me how to do so using a service principal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this curls in java, you can use a restclient like https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: That was going to be my last resort, but is there some sort of native Java client that does what these Curl commands do? I.e. gets an AAD access token, an ACR refresh token and then an ACR access token. I pored through the MSFT Azure Java repos on GitHub but only saw methods to authenticate directly, not return a token.